# Evaluate PHP script using PHP from Java

Tags: java, php, http, nginx, server

I have a simple server in java. It creates a `serversocket` and accepts requests from the browser via `ip` and port. It can server files like images, html ...
Now I would like to include `php`. `Nginx` can somehow communicate with php using the path:

```
 unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

I'm using `linux` btw. and `php7.0-fpm` as is now obvious :

In my understanding `nginx` (which i'm also using) "sends" `php-scripts` to the `php-interpreter` and it responds by sending some other file (images, html ...) back to `nginx`, which then transmits the content to the browser as the response.
My goal is to eliminate replace nginx in this chain by my own server. It is far less developed than nginx (i know and ignore), but the final goal isn't having a fully developed web server.

I'd appreciate it very much if anyone could help me. The internet as a source of knowledge has failed me so far.

***Also***: If my assumptions are wrong, please correct me. This would also be helpful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: NGINX communicates with PHP over TCP port or control socket using [FastCGI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI). What you are trying to do is calling "write a FastCGI client in Java". Just google "java fastcgi client" and you should find a couple of examples over the internet.

Comment: I'll just add this as "that one option that isn't really recommended but you should know it's possible", it would be to call the interpreter using a pipe and use a php script that would parse command line arguments (`$argv`) into `$_GET` and `$_POST`. And then include the actual php script you need to serve (you can get the name for it through a command line argument too). This is the quick but dirty way I solved it a while ago. It gets more and more complex with sessions and cookies and is generally slower than FCGI, so don't try it, it's seriously not recommended

Comment: I have looked into "java fastcgi client" and found libraries and such, but how can i implement this? not using an external component / library ... i also would like to know more about creating a pipe between java and the php interpreter.